# What difference a change in hertz vs duty cycle make to the pitch of a sound?

Tags: sound, duty-cycle

For example, 100 hertz sounds very low, but acquiring that from an online source that doesn't tell me the duty cycle doesn't answer my inquiry into whether a change in the duty cycle will affect the pitch of the sound. Will a 10% duty cycle sound deeper than an 80%? 
Keep in mind, I'm 13 and just getting into Arduino programming (current project: piezo from the manual projects given). Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try on your Arduino + piezo?

Comment: Nothing beats just trying it. You can also put maybe 1K ohms in series with an output and feed it to headphones. To my ear at 100Hz it just sounds raspier at lower duty cycles, but at 500Hz, the low duty cycles sound higher in tone (logical since there is more high frequency content). Anyway, try it! I used an expensive function generator, but you can get similar results yourself.

Comment: Here is a great simulator. Click all the boxes, buttons and slider to change frequency. Also see the spectrum of the sound of a sine, square triangle ad the phase of the harmonics makes a difference. Use your mouse to draw a recurring waveform.  http://www.falstad.com/fourier/  (AUDACITY also has free generator tools in its recording studio)

Comment: from above you can start with a square wave and then draw 10% and 80%. Note that it is not deeper rather more harmonics with a narrow duty cycle and 90% is the same as 10% with the only difference being the average DC level showing in the spectrum as the 1st spike. You can change he spectrum or the time waveform and the other changes. Note the phase of harmonics is complex and you can show up to 30 harmonics I recall. The harmonic that nulls out happens fits in the pulse width , so as duty cycle narrows this null extends out to larger harmonics. At 50% it is different. Can you see why?

Comment: I think I found my answer at, "Note the phase of harmonics is complex..."